# what is s0 Segment in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, collections

I am new to the ConcurrentHashMap want to know how it works so checked the internal implementation of the same. I understand that there are segmentable based on the concurrency level inside it. But what i didn't understand the logic to store one more Segment S0 based on the intialCapacity.

```
public ConcurrentHashMap(int initialCapacity,
                         float loadFactor, int concurrencyLevel) {
    if (!(loadFactor > 0) || initialCapacity < 0 || concurrencyLevel <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (concurrencyLevel > MAX_SEGMENTS)
        concurrencyLevel = MAX_SEGMENTS;
    // Find power-of-two sizes best matching arguments
    int sshift = 0;
    int ssize = 1;
    while (ssize < concurrencyLevel) {
        ++sshift;
        ssize <<= 1;
    }
    this.segmentShift = 32 - sshift;
    this.segmentMask = ssize - 1;
    if (initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        initialCapacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
    int c = initialCapacity / ssize;
    if (c * ssize < initialCapacity)
        ++c;
    int cap = MIN_SEGMENT_TABLE_CAPACITY;
    while (cap < c)
        cap <<= 1;
    // create segments and segments[0]
    Segment<K,V> s0 =
        new Segment<K,V>(loadFactor, (int)(cap * loadFactor),
                         (HashEntry<K,V>[])new HashEntry[cap]);
    Segment<K,V>[] ss = (Segment<K,V>[])new Segment[ssize];
    UNSAFE.putOrderedObject(ss, SBASE, s0); // ordered write of segments[0]
    this.segments = ss;
}
```

can some one explain me the use of the same and Unsafe Object also ?